# Spring StopWatch Issue - A Process has Multiple Processes?

Tags: java, spring, stopwatch

Issue Description: I'm calling a process which has multiple process. Assume process A which has multiple process inside of it.

> Example: Process A calls b process B calls c process C calls D process D process ends. C process ends B process ends finally A process ends. In such a case i'm not sure how to create the Spring StopWatch.

Technical Details: It seems we can only have the process like where A stopwatch ends then only we can start the B stopwatch

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("Spring Stop Watch");
stopWatch.start("A");
processA();
stopWatch.stop();    
stopWatch.start("B");
processB()
stopWatch.stop();
```

If i start the stopwatch before stopping the stopwatch of A it throws errors. Could someone suggest how to proceed or is there is any good stopwatch is available?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think StopWatch supports tracking nested execution. It is a very simple tool.  If you need more sophisticated support you should look at using something like [JaMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/). The approach is similar, but it is more sophisticated.  I think there is a way to use it spring AOP as well - to transparently  add profiling to spring beans.